# node mongodb 3.4 using find with specify fields and toArray does not filter results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Again, using mongo v3.4 and referencing these docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

My example looks like:

```
    const m = this.getCollection(SOME_COLLECTION);
    m.find({
        '_id': {
            $nin: [Ace, Bay],
        },
        'value.someCategory': {
            $type: 'object',
        },
    }, {
        '_id': 0,
        'value.someCategory': 1,
    }).toArray((err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(doc);
        }
    });
```

My `doc` array will return all items that follow my filter of `value.someCategory` of type object, but will not remove the `_id` and will return all fields even though I'd like to specify only the `value.someCategory` field.

Example data in mongo:

```
[
    {
      _id: 'hello',
      value: {
        someCategory: [Object],
        name: 'hello',
        otherCategory: true,
      }
    },
    {
      _id: 'Ace',
      value: {
        someCategory: [Object],
        name: 'Ace',
        otherCategory: true,
      }
    },
    {
      _id: 'testing',
      value: {
        someCategory: null,
        name: 'testing',
        otherCategory: true,
      }
    },
]
```

And expect the result to be:

```
[
    {
      someCategory: [Object],
    },
]
```

Based on the docs linked above, the specified fields should be the second param. I'm wondering now if the use of `toArray` affects the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`.project`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) cursor method instead

```
db.collection('collection')
  .find({ '_id': { '$nin': [Ace, Bay] }, 'value.someCategory': { '$type': 'object' }})
  .project({ '_id': 0, 'value.someCategory': 1 })
  .toArray()
```

Comment: great! ty for the quick reply. I tested just now and works :) One slight difference is that the returned value is included within the key `value` field like: `[{ value: { someCategory: [Object] }}]`. Just wanted to mention this if anyone references this question/answer so they know. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to `someCategory` to top level then you have to use aggregation here. Find query can only filter and limit the data but cannot reshape the output result.

Comment: Ah great, good to know! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use select function and define your required field to projection.

```
const m = await Model.find({
        '_id': {
            $nin: [Ace, Bay],
        },
        'value.someCategory': {
            $type: 'object',
        },
    }).select('-_id value.someCategory').lean();

console.log(m)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using mongoose but thanks for the answer/reply